# How to change the font style in pdf form field using abcpdf in c#?

Tags: c#, abcpdf

How to dynamically change the font used in pdf form field using abcpdf and c#?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please consider reading http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and update your question with what you have tried. If you are stuck, then you'd definitely find help here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See here:](https://www.codehacker.com/ABCpdf/fontref.aspx)

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;
 using System.Web.UI;
 using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
 using System.Drawing;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Net;
 using System.IO;
 using WebSupergoo.ABCpdf8;

 namespace ABCpdfExamples
{
     public partial class test : System.Web.UI.Page
   {
          protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {           
            // ---- Adds a font reference to the document ----
            Doc doc = new Doc();
            doc.FontSize = 48;
            string theFont = "Times-Roman ";
            doc.Font = doc.AddFont(theFont);
            doc.AddText(theFont);
            theFont = "Helvetica-Bold";
            doc.Font = doc.AddFont(theFont);
            doc.AddText(theFont);
            doc.Save(Server.MapPath("~/Results/Output.pdf"));
            doc.Clear();
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: thank you so much for the simple and precise answer @c-Helling